# Ruby On Rails : how to show/hide related div of radio buttons is checked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying using JQuery, not able to proceed. please help me.

```
 radio_button_tag(:radio_btn, 1, true)=> if checked div -- 'abc' show else hide()
    <div id= "abc">
      "abc is executing"
    </div>

 radio_button_tag(:radio_btn, 0)=> if checked div -- 'xyz' show else hide()
   <div id= "xyz">
      "xyz is executing"
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically with:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(e){ // or whatever selector you want
   // do what you want with $(e.currentTarget)
});
```

Made a simple fiddle to demonstrate behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/cc5twser/2/

Comment: Thank you sir. I got using on change function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="radio_btn"]').change(function() {
    var selected = $('input:checked[name="radio_btn"]').val();
    if(selected == '1') {
        $('#xyz').hide();
        $('#abc').show();
    } else if(selected == '0') {
        $('#abc').hide();
        $('#xyz').show();
    }
});
```